# Map size very small in layout view in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts

I am very new to GIS and ArcMap.
 I am currently working on small part of a DEM using ArcHydro toolkit. I have a map which is a clipped part from DEM. When I open it in data view, it looks fine. But for adding legends and scale when I use layout view, it is just visible at the corner of the page. Can't extend it for the print. What can I do?

[image: data view of map]

[image: layout view of map]

Comment: This may help.  Skip to 5:30 for the layout:  https://youtu.be/HnJhg39reZY?t=330

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on the data frame and selecting 'Distribute', then 'Fit to Margins'.

[image: ftm]

Alternatively, you can try selecting a different printer in the 'Page and Print Setup' under **File**.

That seems to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just "zoom in" from the data view to increase the map size in layout view.

This will scale up the map and fit the view in layout. I did the same thing and it worked.